How to get names of crew?
How can you find an up-to-date list of a ship's officers, so you can send a thank-you note? Hard to find on the internet or website.

Write the letter or mail adressed to their function, add the name as good as you can, and send it to the company.
You can request to send the message on to the officer(s) or crew members who were on board when you were there.
You can ask the company for their names but that will take more time and can be denied.
